# Launch mysql/PDO query from URL securely

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been launching all of my user-generated queries from html forms. The form contains method="post" which I use to do the secure prepared statement query of course.
But how can I do this just as securely from a URL. I want to have a URL next to paragraph of text that says "Delete" (rather than using a delete button as part of a form)--And if the user clicks this, I want to have the database delete that record. Can't figure out if this can be done securely anymore with everything moving away from mysql.

How would I get from the link with the delete command to trigger a prepared statement that deletes the record?

Comment: You can create a link to `delete.php?id=someidentifier` and in `delete.php`, use `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/insert-update-and-delete-with-pdo/ - Am sure you could replace `$_POST['filmID']` with `$_GET['filmID']` <= example from it. See also http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059 - Those two pages contain prepared statements using placeholders.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using GET to delete something. See [Well-Intentioned Destruction](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/WellIntentioned-Destruction.aspx) for a cautionary tale. If you want security around these things, use a POST (or even better, DELETE) request and check out [CSRF protection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF))

Comment: @Fred -ii- Funny, I was looking at mustbebuilt site before I posted. Can I just do this: http://example.com/portfolio?FID=$row->FID and then somehow have a query on the same page get that ID and somehow securely delete from the DB?

Comment: Phil has the right idea here.  Post is the way to go.  Exposing it via GET is just asking for trouble.

Comment: See if @Phil wants a go at this. I'm almost afraid I'll end up giving you some *potentially* bad advice.

Comment: You could use url encode and decode , as index.php?base64_encode(id) and on the server you could retrive it using $_GET(base64_decode(id))

Comment: @Icecreamsandwich Interesting. Like this: example.com/delete?base64_encodeFID=$row->FID    and then on my delete.php page just do $the_FID = ( isset( $_GETbase64_decode['FID'] ) ) ? $_GET['FID'] : false;

Comment: Passing variables through URLs is still used on millions of secure sites so there must be a generally accepted and easy way to do this...

Comment: @jaw Using GET and query parameters is fine for non-destructive (see read-only) requests but a secure site should never use them for data manipulation.

Comment: @Phil. not sure what the "read only" is. I did peruse your articles, but unclear if that means I am fine as long as it is not a site someone would care to hack, but that they can easily hack it if they want if you use GET...

Comment: @jaw What I meant is something like `GET /article.php?id=123` is fine if all it does is fetch and display some data, ie nothing is altered by this action. If you wanted to create, update or delete something, I would use a POST request

Comment: @Phil Got it. Thanks. The only way to post is through a form though, right? This would mean there is no secure way to have a link that says delete and have some click that to delete the post on the page?

Comment: @jaw You can use AJAX to send a POST request. You can also make form submit buttons look like plain text links

Comment: @Phil "make form submit buttons look like plain text links"--that's my answer in this case. Thanks!